# Rewrite href links in strings

Tags: regex, azure, url-rewriting

I have a bespoke CMS for a website that stores any uploaded files in the /Assets/ folder.

I'm preparing to move the website to the Azure platform and need some way of rewriting the links within the web pages. Here is what a current link looks like:

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/Assets/some-folder/some-sub-folder/file.doc">link to file</a>
```

What do you suggest would be the best way to change those links to something like:

```
<a href="https://azuresubdomain.blob.core.windows.net/assets/file.doc">link to file</a>
```

There are 100's of pages with tons of links. Also, to throw a spanner in the works, not all links are in sub folders within the assets folder.

Some links are like:

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/Assets/some-folder/file.doc">link to file</a>
```

Suggestions are welcome, I'm open to anything, regex, htmlagilitypack or plain old string.Replace but I can't seem to get my head around how to do it...

Comment: I think it would be best, if you at least try to come up with a solution and then ask again, when you are facing concrete problems. Sure, I could write a perl script that traverses all your docs and changes the links, but that's not my job, it's yours.

Comment: Are the links actually coded as absolute URLs in the CMS?  i.e http://www.thatwasdumb.com/somelink or as relative links like /somelink?

Comment: They are coded as relative ie /Assets/somelink

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the IIS Url Rewriting module which is installed on Azure web roles.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

It basically allows you to define patterns using regex and ouput URLs however you like.  In your case it would be quite simple to rewrite your embedded links to their locations in blob storage.

Comment: Fair enough, but you said in the question you were open to anything including Regex :)

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, I have sorted it, thanks for your comments. If anyone is interested I did a search & replace SQL query on the database.